# forkJoin and interceptor together not working

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I use `forkJoin` for multiple requests. It was working well.

However after I added interceptor, it stopped working.

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (token) {
    request = request.clone({
        url: request.url,
      setHeaders:
      { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'  
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request); 
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

The `forkJoin` code:

```js
const s0 = return this.http.get < IEntityOne > ('u1');
const s1 = return this.http.get < IEntityTwo > ('u2');

forkJoin([s0, s1]).subscribe(
  ([v1, v2]) => {
    console.log(v1);  // <-------- This line of code is never reached
  }
)
```

After some google search, I changed the code as

```js
return next.handle(request).pipe(take(1));
```

But it is still not working.

Comment: Perhaps something else: check Network TAB. There is an error `CORS error`, but I added it.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not something you as a frontender should add; it's a server config

Comment: But why without interceptor there is no CORS Error? After adding that, the issue happens? Out backend should add CORS already.

Comment: Because with the interceptor you're adding the `'Authorization'` header and your server doesn't like that token for some reason. There might be many reasons really; maybe you're also sending some expired cookies? You might want to double check the syntax though; You don't seem to be using `Authorization` in quotes. Also, when you hover over to the CORS error on the tab, what does it say? No access control allow origin?

Comment: Hover over  the CORS, it says `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader`

Comment: Yes so if you google the error, you'll see that it's a server config

Answer (score 1):

The `forkJoin`  operator will only emit once *all* inner observables have completed - so in this case, if one or none of those calls complete successfully, then the `forkJoin` observable will not emit anything (resulting in no logging taking place).

For starters, check your Network tab in whatever developer tools your using to watch these requests and make sure you're getting responses from the backend.

Secondly, as @eko pointed out, try combineLatest. When that observable is created, it will emit any time *any* observable inside completes. This way you would see 2 console logs if both complete successfully, 1 if one finishes, etc.

Lastly, you shouldn't use the `take` operator (within this context) in your interceptor. Since interceptors are meant to act as a "pipe" of sorts (not Angular pipes, just in the sense that Http requests flow through them) using `take(1)` will result in any request to the backend (after the first) not returning at all.

Comment: I made a comment after @eko. It turns out it is CORS error. But I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in the interceptor.